# Swift can't delete last character if it's a space

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm trying to check if the last character is a space within a textfield and remove it. The code below will work if it's not a " " The delegate is all setup, so it's not that.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    var cardNumber = NumberOutlet.text!

    if cardNumber.characters.count > 1 {
        let lastChar = cardNumber[cardNumber.index(before: cardNumber.endIndex)]
        print(lastChar)

        if lastChar == " " {
            cardNumber.remove(at: cardNumber.index(before: cardNumber.endIndex))
        } else {
            _ = cardNumber.characters.dropLast()
        }
        NumberOutlet.text = cardNumber 
    }

    return true
}
```

Just not sure why I can't remove the last character if it's a space??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So the problem with your code is that the function will never know when the user is done typing. Furthermore, the changes that occur within the textfield, take effect AFTER that function returns true. What you should be doing is comparing the replacementString.

So what I recommend is to do this check within the "textFieldShouldReturn" if you allow the return button to close the keyboard.Otherwise if you're trying to prevent spaces within a UITextField, check if the replacementString is equal to " " and if it is, return false.

Answer (score -1):

Try popLast instead of dropLast

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    NumberOutlet.text?.characters.popLast()
    print(NumberOutlet.text)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Never return `true` if you modify the text field's text in `shouldChangeCharactersIn`. And you should only work with the `textField` parameter.